# Converting Perl script to Bash

Tags: linux, perl, bash, wget, tar

I have a Perl script below and I want to convert it to a Bash script but sad to say I have difficulties in Bash. Can anyone help me this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $output = `df -h`;
my $bundle = "`awk -F \'=\' \'{print \$2}\' config.txt`";
my $bundlename = `echo $bundle | awk -F \'/\' \'{print \$11}\'`;
print $output;

system ("wget $bundle");
print "$bundlename\n";
tar();


sub tar {
    my $cd = system ("tar -xzvf $bundlename") ;
    system ("rm -vf $bundlename");
}
```

Please can anyone convert it to Bash script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you've tried, and ask about where you're stuck.  I agree that this is crying out to be a shell script rather than a Perl script; it is not making any use of Perl's distinctive benefits.

Comment: it has already been written by shell in fact in your perl script. you should be fine to convert by yourself. Let us know which part you met problem.

Comment: actually I converted it already and I got problem in the system() side. What is the way to use system() in bash ?

Comment: The system statement simply executes the command in its arguments; the shell does that automatically without needing the word `system` or the quotes around the command as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
bundle=$(awk '$0=$2' FS== config.txt)
bundlename=$(awk '$0=$11' FS=/ <<< "$bundle")
dh -h
wget $bundle
echo $bundlename
tar -xzvf $bundlename
rm -vf $bundlename
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straight-forward direct transliteration of the Perl:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(df -h)
bundle=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
bundlename=$(echo $bundle | awk -F / '{print $11}')  # Possible echo "$bundle" instead?
echo "$output"

wget $bundle
echo "$bundlename"
tar -xzvf "$bundlename"
rm -vf "$bundlename"
```

Given what you do with the `$output` variable, you might as well simply write:

```
bundle=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
bundlename=$(echo $bundle | awk -F / '{print $11}')  # Possible echo "$bundle" instead?
df -h

wget $bundle
echo "$bundlename"
tar -xzvf "$bundlename"
rm -vf "$bundlename"
```

It isn't clear that the `df -h` is providing any benefit to the script; you might simply delete the line instead.

Comment: Thank you everyone. You help a lot the bash script given by @Jonathan Leffler is working . Thank you very much :)